# $lookup between different databases MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As per MongoDB's documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/supported-unsupported/pipeline/lookup-stage/#basic-example), it should be possible to perform a $lookup between two different databases.

```
db.getSiblingDb("sourceDB1").orders.aggregate(
 {
   $lookup: {
     from: { db: "sourceDB2", coll: "catalog" },
     localField: "item",
     foreignField: "sku",
     as: "inventory_docs"
   }
 }
)
```

However, it's not working, and the closest I get is "inventory_docs" as an empty array on the result. I'm using NodeJS.

Comment: Unfortunately you're looking at the documentation for `$lookup` when data federation is configured. The "standard" `$lookup` operator does not currently support joining collections from multiple databases, as mentioned it [its documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-lookup): "_Performs a left outer join to a collection in the same database_"

Comment: That's precisely correct, my good sir. Thank you for pointing out.